# How to avoid code duplication between entry points in Rollup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I want to configure rollup to take a bunch of files on input & produce a bunch of files in `dist` that *share some common code* between them.

Here's the rollup config I use:

```
import path from 'path';
import pathsTransformer from 'ts-transform-paths';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const plugins = [
  peerDepsExternal(),
  alias({
    entries: [
      { find: '@', replacement: path.join(__dirname, '/src') },
      { find: '$root', replacement: __dirname },
    ],
  }),
  nodeResolve(),
  typescript({
    transformers: [() => pathsTransformer()],
  }),
  commonjs({
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
  }),
];

export default [
  {
    input: './src/a.ts',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/a.js',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins,
  },
  {
    input: './src/b.ts',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/b.js',
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins,
  },
];
```

The problem with this set-up is that if `a.ts` & `b.ts` both depend on some code, this common code gets bundled into each output file unnecessarily increasing the bundle size.

Since the `output.format` is `esm` (so, `import`s are available in the output), I'd rather expect rollup to split the shared code between the 2 files in a separate chunk & then make both files `import` that common code ([which seems to be the thing rollup does by default anyway](https://bundlers.tooling.report/code-splitting/multi-pages/)).

I assume the problem to be somewhere around `nodeResolve` or `commonjs` calls, but, I want my dependencies to be bundled. I just don't want to have them *duplicated*.

How do I optimize my output? Here's a [reproduction](https://github.com/Uzwername/rollup-duplication-repro) to visualize it (`dist` included).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By returning an array of objects, you specify to rollup that you want to have *independent* bundles. If you just want to produce multiple files (which was exactly my case) you can just specify `input` as an object.

```
import path from 'path';
import pathsTransformer from 'ts-transform-paths';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const plugins = [
  peerDepsExternal(),
  alias({
    entries: [
      { find: '@', replacement: path.join(__dirname, '/src') },
      { find: '$root', replacement: __dirname },
    ],
  }),
  nodeResolve(),
  typescript({
    transformers: [() => pathsTransformer()],
  }),
  commonjs({
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
  }),
];

export default   {
  input: {
    a: './src/a.ts',
    b: './src/b.ts',
  },
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins,
};
```